# JSF 2 - ReRendering problem after upgrading to richfaces 4.5.17.Final

Tags: richfaces, ajax4jsf

a4j:commandLink and a4j:commandButton are not rendering results properly after upgrading richfaces from 4.2.2.Final to 4.2.17.Final.
Page loads data, only after refreshing page.

Sample:
a4j:commandLink re renders two different a4j:outputPanels.

`<a4j:commandLink actionListener="#{backingBean.loadStudentList}" value="Student List" onclick="jQuery('#sortSpinner').show();" oncomplete="jQuery('#sortSpinner').hide();" render="panel1,panel2">
</a4j:commandLink>`

**Issue**:
While clicking the link, the spinning icon is shown. But "onComplete" is never invoked.
Only on refreshing the page does the icon hide and the page show results.
An exception is shown in glassfish5 log, which implies that the error is in render response phase.

**Exception**: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at **org.richfaces.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.getRendererTypeForResourceName**(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:299)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.getRendererTypeForResourceName(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:218)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.renderComponentResources(PartialViewContextImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:337)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:252)
    at org.richfaces.context.ExtendedPartialViewContext.processPartial(ExtendedPartialViewContext.java:264)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1124)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1905)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:465)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:194)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:151)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:151)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:126)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:223)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:671)

All the related jars are included as per migration guide. 
Can anyone help to solve this?

Comment: line 299 is `if (resourceName.endsWith(".ecss"))`, this looks like you're referencing some resource but the filename is null. Check what resources you're using.

Comment: Rich faces components used in the page are a4j:commandLink and a4j:commandButton. These are working fine with a lower version richfaces4.2.2

Comment: Resource is for example a CSS file, this doesn't seem like RF components are the problem. Check for `<h:outputStyleSheet>` or things like that, or better yet try using a debugger to see what resource is being requested.

Comment: There is no use of resources like <h:outputStyleSheet>. Error occurs in all pages that use a4j:queue.<a4j:status shows that the request was queued, but an empty response was received from the server

Comment: Debugging the UIComponent shows that there are no attributes for the component id  _org_richfaces_queue

Comment: All other UIComponents have name and library as attributes

Comment: Can you tell where the call for `getRendererTypeForResourceName` comes from? I'm not sure the attributes are related. Can you run the RichFaces Showcase? Does it fail with queue as well?

Comment: Another question: what version of JSF are you using?

Comment: The call for getRendererTypeForResourceName  comes during partial rendering.The component id that causes the exception is  _org_richfaces_queue . 
            JSF version : 2.3

Comment: Ok, right, why are you rerendering a queue? Put it somewhere outside of the panels.

Comment: Queue is outside the panel. Also tried by setting a view level queue. Still error occurs.

Comment: Glassfish version is 5

Comment: I've only been able to reproduce this error when I put queue inside the rerendered area, are you sure something else isn't rerendering it?

Comment: For me it was solved by removing a single unnecessary `<a4j:queue />` tag from the code. You could check if replacing a4j:commandLinks with h:commandLink and f:ajax.