# Attribute render of richfaces doesn't work when migrating to jboss 7.4

Tags: jsf, jboss, richfaces

After migrating to jboss 7.4, all the html pages that use the attribute Render of richfaces doesn't work, any idea?

Java8
Richfaces 4.5.0.Final
omnifaces : 2.7

```
09:28:53,389 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-6) Error Rendering View[/views/operations/ci/list.xhtml]: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.richfaces.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.getRendererTypeForResourceName(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:299)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.getRendererTypeForResourceName(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:217)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.getRendererTypeForResourceName(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:217)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.renderComponentResources(PartialViewContextImpl.java:482)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:314)
    at org.richfaces.context.ExtendedPartialViewContext.processPartial(ExtendedPartialViewContext.java:264)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:228)
    at org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContext.processPartial(OmniPartialViewContext.java:122)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1102)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1647)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:442)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:170)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.omnifaces.viewhandler.OmniViewHandler.renderView(OmniViewHandler.java:115)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:199)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf2.impl.listener.phase.CodiLifecycleWrapper.render(CodiLifecycleWrapper.java:126)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:708)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
```

I tried to upgrade Richfaces to the version 4.5.17.Final, it doesn't work too.
Tried also omnifaces 3.0, same issue

Comment: RichFaces was end of life'd back in 2016, https://richfaces.jboss.org/. Maybe this is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152355/jsf-2-rerendering-problem-after-upgrading-to-richfaces-4-5-17-final.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i solved the issue by using the version 4.6.21.ayg de Albert Fernandez

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.github.albfernandez.richfaces</groupId>
<artifactId>richfaces</artifactId>
<version>4.6.21.ayg</version>
```